# The packing radii and the covering radii.

Tags: coding-theory

Lets say I have $C=\{00000, 01101, 10110, 11011\}$

I know the covering radii is given by $e=\frac{1}{2} (d-1)$
So in this example $e=1$.

I know the covering radius of a code C in $(F_q)^n$ is the smallest integer $\rho=\rho(C)$ such that

$\cup_{x \in C}$ $ S(x,\rho)=(F_q)^n$

What is this definition trying to say, how can we interpret it?

In my example, why is the covering radius $\rho=2$?

How do we get this answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the null word:

(00000)

If you generate a list of all words that have a distance of 2 to this word, you get:

(00011) (00101) (00110) (01001) (01010) (01100) (10001) (10010) (10100) (11000)

If you do that with all your codewords, you get 4 sets with 10 words each. Some words are included in several sets.

The complete vector space contains $5^2 = 32$ words. If what you say is true and $p = 2$, then these words are all included in the unification of your 4 sets. This is the meaning of the covering radius. If you do the same with a radius of 1, the complete vector space will not be a subset of the unification of your 4 sets.